# How can this code be optimised, so that it has fewer lines of code and is more consise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make this code shorter. Like a loop or something? It would be great if anyone helps me to make the code shorter so that I can add more nth-child. like nth-child:4, 5.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var src=$(".gallery-grid-item:nth-child(1) img").data("src");
    $.ajax({
        url:src,
        xhrFields:{
            responseType:'blob'
        },
        success:function(data){
            var url=window.URL||window.webkitURL;
            $(".gallery-grid-item:nth-child(1) img").attr("src",url.createObjectURL(data));
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var src=$(".gallery-grid-item:nth-child(2) img").data("src");
    $.ajax({
        url:src,
        xhrFields:{
            responseType:'blob'
        },
        success:function(data){
            var url=window.URL||window.webkitURL;
            $(".gallery-grid-item:nth-child(2) img").attr("src",url.createObjectURL(data));
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var src=$(".gallery-grid-item:nth-child(3) img").data("src");
    $.ajax({
        url:src,
        xhrFields:{
            responseType:'blob'
        },
        success:function(data){
            var url=window.URL||window.webkitURL;
            $(".gallery-grid-item:nth-child(3) img").attr("src",url.createObjectURL(data));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    numberOfNthChilds = 5
    for (let i = 1; i < numberOfNthChilds + 1; i++) {
        var src=$(".gallery-grid-item:nth-child(" + i + ") img").data("src");
        $.ajax({
            url:src,
            xhrFields:{
                responseType:'blob'
            },
            success:function(data){
                var url=window.URL||window.webkitURL;
                $(".gallery-grid-item:nth-child(" + i + ") img").attr("src",url.createObjectURL(data));
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What if the nth-child is not a number. Suppose if the .gallery-grid-item increase dynamically. I don't want to declare number of nth-child like this : "numberOfNthChilds = 5" 

Thank you  !

Comment: this is worked for me. Thank you, @pzutils . You are awesome. 

 const myimage = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-grid-item");
    for (let i = 1; i < myimage.length + 1; i++) {